# Uploading large videos to Cloudinary in Chunks using React Native Expo Go

Tags: react-native, expo, blob, cloudinary

I have an app that allows users to upload their videos.
We need users to be able to upload long videos, that are often over 100mg in size.

I'm struggling to upload those videos to Cloudinary.
I'm using Expo Go, React Native.

I've tried implementing chunks, but I can't even get axios / fetch to upload a full video using blob. It seems it can't recognize the blob.

```
 const handleSendChunkedVideo = async (uri) => {

    const response = await fetch(uri);
    const blob = await response.blob();

    console.log('uri', uri);

    await send(blob);
}


const send = async (piece) => {
    const YOUR_CLOUD_NAME = "";
    const YOUR_UNSIGNED_UPLOAD_PRESET = "";

    const POST_URL =
        "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + YOUR_CLOUD_NAME + "/auto/upload";

    const formdata = new FormData();

    formdata.append("file", piece);
    formdata.append("cloud_name", YOUR_CLOUD_NAME);
    formdata.append("upload_preset", YOUR_UNSIGNED_UPLOAD_PRESET);

    try {

        await fetch(POST_URL, {
            method: 'post',
            body: formdata,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',
            }

        })
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(data => {
                console.log('Upload Result', data);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('err', err);
                uploadResult = 'failed'
            });
}
    catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
    }
```

This is the error I get:

```
Upload Result Object {
  "error": Object {
    "message": "Missing required parameter - file",
  },
}
```

How do I get expo to be able to at least upload a blob, and not Base64, so that then I can work on the chunking part?
rn-fetch-blob doesn't work with my expo app, so I can't use it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This link here appears to hold the solution: [React-Native expo POST Blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66372873/react-native-expo-post-blob)

Looks like fetching a blob is not supported and you can replace the blob with
`` form.append('file', { uri, name: 'media', type: `image/${type}` } as any) ``

Alternatively, you may need a middleware like Multer to receive and process the multiform data before passing it over.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll work on this solution and see if it works on a full image. But, if I wanted to chunk the upload, how do I split the blob in this format?